# Count aggregate does not work using PIVOT in MSSQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using a pivot to generate a cross-tabulation report to summarize data using MSSQL Server.  However, when I run my query, it didn't produce the result which I expect to.

This is the sql pivot query:

```
    select Station, 
       [1] as Good,
       [3] as Bad,
       [5] as Deactivated,
       [6] as Deleted
       --StateCount
from
(
select m.MetaData1 as Station,
       t.ID,
       --m.StateID,
       count(t.[State]) as StateCount
from MasterTags m inner join TagStates t on t.ID = m.StateID
where (m.MetaData1 is not null and m.MetaData1 != '') and (m.PIServerID = 1)
group by m.MetaData1, t.ID, m.StateID, t.[State]
) as result
PIVOT (count(result.StateCount) for ID in ([1], [3], [5], [6])) pvt
```

Result:

```
Station | Good  | Bad  | Deactivated | Deleted | StateCount
------- +-------+------+-------------+---------+-----------
ABY     |   0   |  0   |     0       |   1     |     4
ABY     |   0   |  1   |     0       |   0     |    18
ABY     |   1   |  0   |     0       |   0     |    40
FTB     |   0   |  1   |     0       |   0     |    10
FTB     |   1   |  0   |     0       |   0     |   121
KIK     |   0   |  1   |     0       |   0     |     1
KIK     |   1   |  0   |     0       |   0     |    45
```

I have included the `StateCount` column above to show the actual `count(t.[State])` values.  But, instead I got a value of `1` for each of these columns (Good, Bad, Deactivated, Deleted) in the final result set. I would expect the `StateCount` values will be the data for these columns (as shown below).

Expected Output:

```
Station | Good  | Bad  | Deactivated | Deleted
------- +-------+------+-------------+--------
ABY     |   40  |  18  |     0       |   4
FTB     |  121  |  10  |     0       |   0
KIK     |   45  |   1  |     0       |   0
```

This is my first time to use a pivot relation operator in a table-valued expression.  Perhaps I don't really understand how to use it correctly.  Is my pivot query wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `group by m.MetaData1, t.ID, m.StateID, t.[State]` - check the grouping and try again. That is, run the query *without* the PIVOT. At the very least, t.ID is probably "grouping" one-row-at-a-time.

Comment: @user2864740 I already have that grouping in the table-valued expression.  I may need the PIVOT in my query in order to achieve cross-tabulation data.  Is this achievable in one select statement using PIVOT or should I create a stored procedure to process the data?

Comment: well as you have already counted the number inside the select (count(t.[State]) as StateCount) when it comes to the pivot you already have only one row for that particular id and it counts a one. So inside the pivot don't use a count. just use a select i.e. PIVOT (result.StateCount for ID in ([1], [3], [5], [6])) pvt

Comment: @Sam, yeah, makes sense.  I did that and now the PIVOT is working correctly.  Thank you for your suggestion, you have saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my sql query isn't correctly structured the way I want to return the correct result.  In order to arrive to my desired output, this is how I wrote the sql statement with PIVOT relation operator with table-valued expression.

```
    select Station, 
       [1] as Good,
       [3] as Bad,
       [5] as Deactivated,
       [6] as Deleted
from
(
select m.MetaData1,
       m.MetaData1 as Station,
       t.ID,
from MasterTags m inner join TagStates t on t.ID = m.StateID
where (m.MetaData1 is not null and m.MetaData1 != '') and (m.PIServerID = 1)
group by m.MetaData1, t.ID
) as result
PIVOT (count(result.MetaData1) for ID in ([1], [3], [5], [6])) pvt
```

That gives me the correct result.